# Prevent daterangepicker from closing when clicking anywhere on browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

as mention in the question above, how can prevent daterangepicker from closing other than by pressing `Apply` and `Cancel` button, because its triggering all the function even without pressing `Apply`.

Below is my code :

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="add" placeholder="Select a Start & End Date Here" class="form-control">
```

javascript

```
$('#add').daterangepicker({
        autoUpdateInput: false,
        "timePicker": true,
        "autoApply": true,
        "startDate": moment(),
        "endDate": null,
        locale: { 
            format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
        }
        }, function(start, end, label) {
                var start_date = start.toISOString();
                var end_date = end.toISOString();
                var selected_character_list = character_table.rows('.selected').data();
                if (selected_character_list.length == 0){
                    alert("Select character");
                    return
                }
});
```

**UPDATE** **:** Here's a working sample https://jsfiddle.net/5dxhy8gk/3/

As you can see if you press outside the date range picker window, the alert function is still executed

Comment: use backdrop:false

Comment: sorry, but it didn't work

Comment: share a working fiddler for better understanding!

Comment: working fiddler added

Comment: I have reply to your question please check @M.Izzat

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue I have downloaded the daterangepicker.min.js and comment out the method outsideClick body.

```
outsideClick: function(t) {
  // var e = R(t.target);
  // "focusin" == t.type || e.closest(this.element).length || e.closest(this.container).length || e.closest(".calendar-table").length || (this.hide(), this.element.trigger("outsideClick.daterangepicker", this))
}
```

And include the js inside my file

[Working Example link](https://jsfiddle.net/swazruby/985vh7qa/)